# How to add buttons and check boxes on top of programmatically added Google maps android v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

So I programmatically added Google into my app and it works pretty good but I can't figure out how to add buttons or options on top of the maps for things like switching map types, searching locations etc. here is my current code:

```
public class GoogleMaps extends FragmentActivity {
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);

        mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment(){
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                GoogleMap map = mMapFragment.getMap();
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                if (map != null){
                    UiSettings settings = map.getUiSettings();
                    settings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        };       
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mMapFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to put the map in a `FrameLayout` in your XML file along side with a `RelativeLayout/LinearLayout` that will overlap the map Fragment and that way by placing the buttons into the `RelativeLayout/LinearLayout` the will be on top of the map.

like so:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/corneredmap" >
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

another option that I think demands much more work is to create your own `CustomMapFragment` that extends `SupportMapFragment` and add to it your desired buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to hardcore Google maps because the xml was not working, getting a fragment error, I will try creating a custom map fragment and report.

Comment: Welp, I just tried the xml again for the hell of it and magically it worked so you have helped me out more than you know! Wish i could give you more internet points, thanks a bunch!